# Django : How to rollback in save method

Tags: django, django-models

Our app need to sync his data within a LDAP backend.
Eg : Each time a user in saved in django some of the data must be saved in LDAP.
For that, we use the django ldap backend which work great.
At start we wrote the sync code in post_save signal of the member. Sync work well, but this way, we can't rollback database save if LDAP fail for any reason.
So we plane to wrote sync code in overridded save method. But here too we can't find a way to rollback.
The closest solution we have is :

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    try:
        self.sync_with_ldap()
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        transaction.commit()
```

This code return a TransactionManagementError : "This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active."

How can we do to :

- Rollback inside a save method
- Or another way to get our two models synced each overs

Comment: Instead of syncing with ldap have you thought to use ldap as your authentication backend? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-auth-ldap/1.2.0

Comment: We use LDAP as backend https://github.com/jlaine/django-ldapdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, was very simple :

Just have to decorate with @transaction.atomic

```
@transaction.atomic
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    try:
        self.sync_to_ldap()
    except:
        raise
```